# Sql sever Replace function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have file Location in my table like

FileLocation :-  "\Saurabh\Rahul\Saurabh\ABC.text"

I need to replace "Saurabh" with "Ramesh" but i need to replace first "Saurabh"  word only not all the "saurabh" which is in the string.

i tried with

```
    select REPLACE(FILELOCATION,'saurabh','Ramesh')
```

How can i achive ?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

You can Use  [STUFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx) and [CHARINDEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms186323.aspx) functions.

```
DECLARE @str varchar(100) = '\Saurabh\Rahul\Saurabh\ABC.text'
SELECT STUFF(@str, CHARINDEX('saurabh', @str), LEN('saurabh'), '')
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
\\Rahul\Saurabh\ABC.text
```

Answer (score 1):

To replace only the first occurence of a word in a string you can write as:

```
DECLARE @FileLocation VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ReplaceSubString VARCHAR(MAX),@NewSubString  VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @FileLocation = '\\Saurabh\Rahul\Saurabh\ABC.text'
SET @ReplaceSubString = 'Saurabh'
SET @NewSubString = 'Ramesh'

SELECT STUFF ( @FileLocation ,
              CHARINDEX(@ReplaceSubString, @FileLocation) ,
              Len(@ReplaceSubString) ,
              @NewSubString
             )
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://rextester.com/RAEYTP25310)</kbd>